# Can RGB Fans work without them being lighted up?

Tags: sata, fan, desktop-computer, led, rgb

i did a small research and still don't if RGB fans can work without the being lighted up. the real question is:

- Can i connect only the SATA POWER of the RGB controller? without connecting the MB?
- And, would they work without lighting up?

Comment: Show the wiring of the fan and RGB controller?  and what does SATA have to do with this?

Comment: Because the controller needs SATA POWER to work.